# How to program a UserForm Based on Selections of Markets using ListBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the following UserForm:

[image]

The underlying Subs that were created are:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

What I basically wanted to do was: Selecting the relevant markets and on that basis entering those exchanges that were selected into separate cells in a listed format on the active sheet.

A process example in short: Selects Xetra, Xontro and Euronext --> Clicks OK --> populates A1 to A3 with the above mentioned names.

I would send my ideas but since I am relatively new in VBA and do not know how to take values out of a ListBox and then use them in a Sub. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of examples online. Here is a basic example which puts selected items in A1 (and down) of sheet1.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        j = j + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(j, 1).Value = ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure you need to declare a value for j too